# How create collections names dynamically (depending on the user info)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want create a more deep collection.. data more organize.

I know how to access the data, how retrieve information, but I don't exactly know how to create the schema.

this is my actual schema:

```
var MySchema = new Schema ({
    event: { 
            full: String,
            date: String,
            name: String,
    },
    person: {
            name: String,
            phone: String,
            email: String,
            obs: String
    }
});
```

And I want change for:

```
var BookingSchema = new Schema ({
   monday: {
        event: { 
                full: String,
                date: String,
                name: String,
        },
        person: {
                name: String,
                phone: String,
                email: String,
                obs: String
        }
    },
   friday: {
        event: { 
                full: String,
                date: String,
                name: String,
        },
        person: {
                name: String,
                phone: String,
                email: String,
                obs: String
        }
    },
   saturday: {
        event: { 
                full: String,
                date: String,
                name: String,
        },
        person: {
                name: String,
                phone: String,
                email: String,
                obs: String
        }
    }
   sunday: {
        event: { 
                full: String,
                date: String,
                name: String,
        },
        person: {
                name: String,
                phone: String,
                email: String,
                obs: String
        }
    }
});
```

This is not very dry, so I was wondering if I can change the names of the weeks dynamically. If I can, how to do?

If this is possible, the real schema would be:

```
   dinamicallyDay: {
        event: { 
                full: String,
                date: String,
                name: String,
        },
        person: {
                name: String,
                phone: String,
                email: String,
                obs: String
        }
    }
```

This is my first questions, now me second.

If the first question is possible, how can I create entrances inside the dinamicallyDay?

For example, someone wants to register to the monday, but this day already exists in my database, I want put this register inside, like this:

```
   monday: {
        1: {
            event: { 
                    full: String,
                    date: String,
                    name: String,
            },
            person: {
                    name: String,
                    phone: String,
                    email: String,
                    obs: String
            }
        }
    }
```

This is possible?

If so.. can you guys help me??

Comment: Your english is not very good and you are not expressing a clear intent by listing too much detail. What do you want to achieve? It almost sounds like a "booking system" where you want to avoid overlapping dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Schema` constructor accepts an object, so there's no reason you can't build that dynamically.

```
var mySchema = {}

['mon', 'fri', 'satur', 'sun'].forEach(function(day) {
    mySchema[ day + 'day' ] = [{
        event: { 
                full: String,
                date: String,
                name: String,
        },
        person: {
                name: String,
                phone: String,
                email: String,
                obs: String
        }
    }];
});

var BookingSchema = new Schema(mySchema);
```

Note that I changed that into an array, so now you can push more events to the same day doing something like

```
db.update({'Search here'}, {
 $push : {
    friday :  {
         event: { 
                    full: 'value',
                    date: 'value',
                    name: 'value'
         },
         person: {
                    name : 'value',
                    phone: 'value',
                    email: 'value',
                    obs  : 'value'
         }
    }
});
```